# Can't define href element of laravel's view

Tags: php, laravel, view

I have two routes defined in my laravel web.php file.

```
Route::get('/art', ['uses'=>'Aboutcontroller@getArticles', 'as'=>'articles']);
Route::get('/art/{id}', ['uses'=>'Aboutcontroller@getArticle', 'as'=>'article']);
```

I want to use them in my view file as 'href' property of my Hyperlink.

When i wrote the following code:

> ```
> *<a href="/art">I link </a> </br>
> <a href="/art/800">II link </a> </br>*
> ```

works fine.

but when I want to use routes by it't name an parameter (as described in a help topic of laravel's official site), it gives me the error:

```
<a href="<?php echo route('article', ['id' => 123]); ?>">IV link </a>
```

image is included.

What I have a mess?

I'm using version 8.2 of laravel. It is current for now.

[image]

Comment: You geeting this error from your IDE only. Why this is not enough instead of? `{{ route('article', ['id' => 123]) }}`

Comment: @sta I'm just learning laravel. and I want to set laravel's hyperlink without blade format, via PHP, But I can't believe what's wrong.

Comment: In PHP,  there are no any function called `route`, so your IDE will throw an error.

Comment: Is this in a `.php` file?

Comment: @sta Now it's working fine without any correction, I still can't believe what happened. Thanks a lot and sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::get('art', [\App\Http\Controllers\Aboutcontroller::class, 'getArticles'])->name('getArticles');
Route::get('art/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\Aboutcontroller::class, 'getArticles'])->name('getArticles');
```

or

```
Route::get('art', 'App\Http\Controllers\Aboutcontroller@getArticles')->name('getArticles');
Route::get('art/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Aboutcontroller@getArticles')->name('getArticles');
```

blade files

```
<a href="{{ route('getArticles') }}">IV link </a>
```

parameter

```
<a href="{{ route('getArticles',['id' => 1]) }}">IV link </a>
```